# case insensitive LDAP searches

Tags: ldap, case-insensitive, ldap-query, apacheds

What is the syntax for performing a case-insensitive match on a `uid` attribute?  If attribute definition matters then how would that be changed?

In particular I am using ApacheDS for my LDAP store.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`(uid=miXedCaseUSer)` will match a `uid` of `mixedcaseuser`.

According to the [OID Description for 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1 - Userid](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1.html) `userId` is defined to have `EQUALITY MATCHING RULE caseIgnoreMatch`

This means it is one of the attribute definitions that employ case-insensitive matching by default.

Comment: Of course, but SO imposes a waiting period for that.  Besides, I'm not even convinced mine is the best answer.  One thing that annoys me here is that the search type is modeled into the attribute, what do I do if I now want case-sensitive searches on uid?  Are there other ways?  There must be a way to change case sensitivity in the search... I hope.

Comment: Try overriding the default matching rule for the attribute using extensible matching: (uid:caseExactMatch:=mixCaseUSer). If it works it will probably be a lot slower than using the default matching rule for the attribute.

Comment: How can I apply `caseExactMatch` on `uid`? Does it possible?

Comment: how to give this syntax in .properties file?

Answer (score 5):

I think they are case insensitive by default, unless its a password attribute.