# Jboss LDAP login module using non-case sensitive

Tags: java, jboss, ldap

I have set up a login module in my JBoss 6.0 server using Jboss LDAP Login module like that:

```
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" flag="sufficient">
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url">ldap://@ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DOMAINSERVER@:@DOMAINSERVER_PORT@</module-option>
            <module-option name="java.naming.security.protocol">ssl</module-option>     
            <module-option name="principalDNSuffix">****</module-option>
            <module-option name="rolesCtxDN">dc=***,dc=**,dc=**</module-option>
            <module-option name="uidAttributeID">sAMAccountName</module-option>
            <module-option name="roleAttributeID">memberOf</module-option>
            <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN">true</module-option>
            <module-option name="searchScope">ONELEVEL_SCOPE</module-option>  
            <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option> 
            <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID">cn</module-option>
            <module-option name="defaultRole">authenticated</module-option>
            <module-option name="debug">true</module-option>
        </login-module>
```

What is the syntax for performing a case-insensitive match on a "uidAttributeID" attribute for Username? If attribute definition matters then how would that be changed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2017406/687514) perhaps relevant to you?

Comment: The attribute already is case-insensitive, see the link.