# PHP Search Upper and Lowercase letters

Tags: php, search, ldap

Is there a way to get PHP to search and come back results no matter the difference of upper or lowercase letters. My current code searches and only comes back with exact results of upper and lower case. So i made it all lowercase, but i want the results to have the correct uppercase letters for names.

It's searching via LDAP. The values are information from Active Directory, the search is searching the names of people, and giving the results such as Phone Number etc of that person

Here is my code:

```
// Address Book Search
$search .= "<div class='border'>\n";
$search .= "<h1>Search for Staff</h1>";
$search .= '<form class="search-form-wrapper" method="GET">
                <input type="text" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Search for Staff..." required>
                <input type="submit" value="go" id="submit">
            </form><br><br>';

if (count($staff)) {
    if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
        $query = strip_tags($_GET['q']);
        $query = str_replace('%27', "'", $query);
        $query = strtolower($query);
        $search .= "<table class='address_book'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Phone</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Email</th><th>Dept</th></tr>\n";
        foreach ($staff as $key => $details) {
            $details['displayname'] = strtolower($details['displayname']);
            if(substr_count($details['displayname'], $query)){
            $search .= "<tr><td>{$details['displayname']}</td>\n";
            $search .= "<td>{$details['title']}</td>\n";
            $search .= "<td>{$details['telephonenumber']}</td>\n";
            $search .= "<td>{$details['mobile']}</td>\n";
            $search .= "<td><a href='mailto:{$details['mail']}'>{$details['mail']}</a></td>\n";
            $search .= "<td>{$details['department']}</td>\n";
            $search .= "</tr>\n";
            }
        }
        $search .= "</table>\n";
    }
}
$search .= "</div><br>";
```

Comment: search where, in db? Seems like it. Sure there's a way; what do you have for values in it? Just ignore case.

Comment: It's searching via LDAP. The values are information from Active Directory, the search is searching the names of people, and giving the results such as Phone Number etc of that person.

Comment: @Mooticus you should look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017152/case-insensitive-ldap-searches

Comment: Just like I said earlier, "ignore case" - `caseIgnoreMatch` ^

Comment: How does this work, since im using PHP to search the string, for the values?

Answer (score 0):

I used stristr($query) to search case insensitive.